# Create a program that maintains a binary of product information in stock with records in the form: {int product_id, int product_quantity}

Tags: python, java

> Create a program that maintains a binary of product information in stock with records in the form: `{int product_id, int product_quantity}`.
> Implement the import, set, list and export functions:
>
> - `import {file}`: reads a text file where each line contains 2 integers separated by a space, the first number represents the product code and the second the new offer
> - `set {id {{q}`: changes the offer of a product with code `{id}` to `{q}`. If the product code does not exist, it is created
> - `list {id}`: prints the product offer with code `{id}`. If the password does not exist, print "not found"
> - `export {file}`: creates a text file corresponding to the import file.

My code in Python it runs normally but in java I have a hard time, could anyone help me?

Python Code :

```
def import_file(file):
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        sline = []
        for line in lines:
          xline=line.split(" ")
          sline.append(xline)
    return sline        
        
def set_file(idf,q,sline):
    for i in sline:
        if idf in i:
            sline[sline.index(i)][1] = q + "\n"
            return "Change succeeded"
    sline.append([idf,q])
    return "New code added"

def list_file(idf,sline):
    for i in sline:
        if idf in i:
            return sline[sline.index(i)][1]
    return "Not found"       

def export_file(name,sline):
    with open(name,'w') as f:
        for lines in sline:
            f.write(lines[0] + ' ' + lines[1])
                                     
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    choice=int(input("1:Import file\n 2:Set \n 3:List \n 4:Export file \n 5:Quit \n :"))
    if choice == 1:
        print("Importing file...")
        use=import_file(input("Insert the path of the file:"))
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Setting file...")
        print(set_file(input("Insert id:"),input("Insert quantity:"),use))
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Listing file...")
        print(list_file(input("Insert id:"),use))
        print(use)
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Exporting file...")
        print(export_file(input("Name of the exported file:"),use))
    elif choice == 5:
        print("Goodbye")
        loop = 0
```

Comment: What is your question? Please be specific.

Comment: How can I do the above with Java ?

Comment: It is unlikely you will find someone here to convert your Python code to Java. That's not what this site is for. If you add what you have attempted (the Java code), we can help you with specific errors. Please stop by the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: obviously i dont ask for that , and sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: What I can not understand is, let's say the following in Java , how we do it.     
 def import_file(file):
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        sline = []
        for line in lines:
          xline=line.split(" ")
          sline.append(xline)
    return sline

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ImportFile{
  public static String[][] importFile(String fileName){
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    try {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(sc.nextLine());
      }
      sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    String[][] slines = new String[lines.size()][];
    
    int count = 0;
    for(String line:lines){
      String[] xline = line.split(" ");
      slines[count] = xline;
      count++;
    }
    
    return slines;
  }
  static void printDoubleArray(String[][] arr){
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++ ){
      System.out.print("[");
      for(int j = 0;j<arr[i].length;j++ ){
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
        if(j != arr[i].length-1) System.out.print(", ");
      }
      System.out.print("]");
      if(i != arr.length-1) System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String [][] fileContent = importFile("text.txt");
    printDoubleArray(fileContent);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not want the whole code but a part of it, I wrote it below in the comments but really thank you for solving my question. Sorry also for the incorrect wording of the question.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: text (The system cannot find the file specified) . Why do I get such an exception?

Comment: I used the file name text.txt as an example but use whatever file name you need

Comment: I changed it but I have the same exception no matter what I use

Comment: If your doing this via terminal make sure the file is in the same directory as the java class file. If your using eclipse or some IDE make sure it is in the directory where the src/ and bin/ are located. If neither of those work, you could put the entire file location path like /Users/... /fileName

Comment: Thanks a lot, it ran normally.

Comment: Ben Once I realized that the code in Java does not do what I wrote and I did the same in python, can you help me please?

Comment: I only translated one of your functions for you, not the entire program. I figured that you would be able to figure out the rest. I did not completely understand your goal so I did what i understood. My apologies

Comment: I will try to understand, the truth is that java is more difficult than Python but I will give my best. Thanks again Ben. Have a nice and productive day! :)